# Subversion (SVN) Propfind 405 error

Tags: svn, apache, zend-studio, apache-config

I am brand new to Subversion and have been told that this is the best thing since sliced bread. I have tried Google, and I am just drawing blanks on what is wrong and have tried multiple different suggestions. I get the following error.

> The Location information has been specified incorrectly.
>
> svn: Propfind of '/svn': 405 Method not allowed (http://IPADDRESS) with IPADDRESS being the IP of my server.

I get this when I try to log in through Zend Studio. I use the following to try to login:

URL: http://IPADDRESS/svn/ 
 Username: fakeuser 
 Password: fakepassword

I believe that the issue is around this file because of the error "Location Information has been specified incorrectly". This file is included in the httpd.conf file. I have restarted Apache and there are not errors when restarting Apache.

```
<Location /project1>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /home/jhughes/project1
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/jhughes/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/jhughes/.svn-auth-file
   Satisfy Any
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I have spent a few hours on this and cannot get it.

I am not using a proxy server. I am using the IP address of the server, because I have multiple domains on the server and thought this may be an issue.

Comment: are you using a proxy server between your client and the server?

Comment: No I am not using a proxy.  I am using the ipaddress of the server.  I do have multiple websites on this server, so I think I have to use the ip address for that reason.

Comment: the snippet looks very similar to an apache config - is it?

Comment: Yes, the snippet is in the apache config (through an include).  The apache file does restart properly and has been restarted.  It is included on the last line of the httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your URL is partly to blame - try something more along the lines of

http://username:password@IPADDRESS/svn/project1/

Comment: I tried this.  I get the same 405 error.  I tried it with /svn/project1/ and just /svn/ just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more a question for Server Fault, but here's my take on it:

Problem 1. Location needs to be "/project1" not just "project1" ... that's probably the source of your Location error. You can look in Apache's logs for things like this (possibly `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`, but it depends on your OS and settings).

Possible problem: I've never seen an SVN repository setup in a user folder. Most likely you need to look at the settings for SVN itself and make sure the SVNPath in Apache matches it. Usually its something like `/svn`. Again it might be setup that way, just something I've never seen.

What you've been told is true. SVN rocks, though setting it up through DAV is not usually for the faint of heart. Does Zend Studio support connecting to SVN through SSH? That's far easier to get going.

Comment: There is a tab on the zend studio svn respository called ssh.  It states the port is set to 22 and has password checked.  Other then that not much else.

Also I have the location set to /project1.

<Location /project1>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /home/jhughes/project1
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/jhughes/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/jhughes/.svn-auth-file
   Satisfy Any
   Require valid-user
</Location>

I tried again and don't see much in the way of help in the error log

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put your configuration inside a `<Directory>` block rather than a `<Location>` block.  I originally had my configuration inside a `<Location>` block and was getting endless `PROPFIND` errors until I moved it into a `<Directory>` block.

Here's my working configuration (not for SVN, just a stand-alone WebDAV server):

```
Alias /webdav /webdav
DavLockDB "/etc/apache2/var/DavLock"
<Directory /webdav>
    Allow from all
    DAV On
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Make sure the `webdav` directory is `chown`ed to your web user (e.g. `www-data`).